# HTML/CSS Beginner, struggling to make image inline with text

Tags: html, css

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

I am trying to get that text box at the bottom of the page to align with the second image down so that it is in the bottom right corner. I have made a big div containing the images and text.

```css
body {
  background-color:rgb(white);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

p {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 22px;

}

.centre {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top:10px;
  text-align:center;
}

nav{
  margin-top:0px;
  width:100%;
  background:rgb(97, 157, 255);
  overflow:auto;
}

nav a{
  display: block;
  padding:20px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}

nav a:hover{
  background-color:rgb(203, 204, 212);
  transition:0.4s;
}
ul{
  padding:0;
  margin:0 250px;
  list-style:none;
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: fixed top;
}

li{
  margin-bottom:-4px;
  margin-top:-2.5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  float:left;
}

.logo1 img{
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  width:16%;

}

.collage{
  display: block;
  margin:auto;
  width:70%;
  border:1.5px solid rgba(112, 128, 144, 0.5);
}

.collage img{
  width:40%;
  height:300px;
  display: inline-block;

}

.collage p{
  border:1.5px solid rgba(112, 128, 144, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPEhtml>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout_91893.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="logo1">
  <a href = "index_91893.html"><img src="Maunga_Club_white.png"></a>
</div>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href = "page1_91893.html">Available Cabins</a></li>
    <li><a href = "membership_91893.html">Club Membership</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Bookings</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">FAQ</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<p style="text-align:center;"> Enjoy the winter season with your family and friends in our premium cabins and chalets based on the Maunga Summit.</p>
<h1>The Kakapo Chalet</h1>
<img src="cabin_exterior.jpg" alt="picture" class="centre">
<div class="collage">
<img src="bunk_room.jpg" alt="picture">
<img src="cabin_view.jpg"alt="picture">
<img src="hallway.jpg">
<p> The Kakapo Chalet is a great choice for a medium to large number of guests.</p>
</div>
</html>
```

not too sure if a lot of the code in my CSS is relevant either but I've just been experimenting with inline blocks and stuff like that. Can someone please show me how I can align the text with the image?

expected the text box to align with bottom left image.

Comment: you can try to set the <p> as inline-block

Comment: [Create a snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet) so people can edit, test and check your code easily. You'll get more answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;`, with `word-break`, `vertical-align` to make `<p>` display the same as image and set `margin`, `padding` to have same space.

```css
.collage {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 70%;
    border: 1.5px solid rgba(112, 128, 144, 0.5);
}

.collage img {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1.5px solid rgba(112, 128, 144, 0.5);
    width: 40%;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;

}

.collage p {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1.5px solid rgba(112, 128, 144, 0.5);
    height: 300px;
    width: 40%;
    word-break: break-all;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="collage">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/300/200" alt="picture">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/200" alt="picture">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/300/200">
  <p> The Kakapo Chalet is a great choice for a medium to large number of guests.</p>
</div>
```

The code above look bad in very small screen, click on Full page to view in larger size.

#### Flex box

You may use CSS [Flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.collage{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width:70%;
  border:1.5px solid rgba(112, 128, 144, 0.5);
}

.collage p,
.collage img{
  padding:20px;
  border:1.5px solid rgba(112, 128, 144, 0.5);
  width:50%;

}

.collage * {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* I add this for use width: 50% WITH border so that it can be fit in outer div perfectly. */
}
```

```html
<div class="collage">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/300/200" alt="picture">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/200" alt="picture">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/300/200">
  <p> The Kakapo Chalet is a great choice for a medium to large number of guests.</p>
</div>
```

#### Grid

Or you may use CSS [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

```css
.collage {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    margin: auto;
    width: 70%;
    border: 1.5px solid rgba(112, 128, 144, 0.5);
}

.collage img {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1.5px solid rgba(112, 128, 144, 0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.collage p {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1.5px solid rgba(112, 128, 144, 0.5);
    word-break: break-all;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="collage">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/300/200" alt="picture">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/200" alt="picture">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/300/200">
  <p> The Kakapo Chalet is a great choice for a medium to large number of guests.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Flexbox` layout might be a good choice as it would simplify the overall layout for you?

```css
.collage {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
}

.collage img {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 40%;
}

.collage,
.collage>img,
.collage>p {
  border: 1.5px solid rgba(112, 128, 144, 0.5);
}

.collage>img,
.collage>p {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0.1rem;
  clear: none;
  width: calc( 50% - 0.4rem);
  height: 300px;
}

.collage>p {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="collage">
  <img src="bunk_room.jpg" alt="bunk">
  <img src="cabin_view.jpg" alt="cabin">
  <img src="hallway.jpg" alt='hallway'>
  <p> The Kakapo Chalet is a great choice for a medium to large number of guests.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks this looks like it will work! I have no idea what's going on but ill do some research on what flex boxes are real quick